# OWA through a Watchguard Firebox 550e using Fireware XTM v11

Tags: firewall, outlook-web-app, watchguard

I have just implemented a watchguard firebox 550e on my network.  I can access the OWA (exchange 2003) without an issue from within the network.  When I access it from outside, I login and a folder list appears on the left, but every view on the right says "there are no items to show in this view" (this applies to all views - mail, contact, journal, etc).

I have incoming HTTP and HTTPS proxies set to forward requests on the MX record to the Exchange server.  Email is flowing in and out without an issue, there are just no individual items listed on OWA from the outside.

Everything that I have located on the internet states that setting up HTTP and HTTPS proxies are all that should be needed for OWA which resides on the Exchange server (which is how I am set up).

Any suggestions would be would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I continued to research this, and it seems that the WebDAV that OWA uses was being blocked by the firewall.  I configured the HTTP proxy to allow additional WebDAV access to the exchange server and that resolved the issue.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to read this!!

Comment: Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

80 and 443 should cover it for OWA, that's all we have open for it, too.

Any chance you're not logging in as the user you're intending to log in as?  Might double-check the default OWA login domain, or specify domain\username when you log into OWA externally.  Or log in as a few different users, to make sure it's not something particular to the mailbox you're logging into.

Comment: I have tried multiple accounts.  The folder list is valid for each account and I see email when I access OWA behind the firewall, just not outside the network.

Comment: What happens if you try to send mail from OWA after logging in from outside?  Is it a single-server setup?  Any chance the firewall is pointing you to OWA on a different server than you're accessing from inside?  I'm not sure where to start if it's a permissions problem.  Anything in the security logs?